# Why is matrix trace involved in the generator of brownian motion?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, stochastic-processes

Let $x_t$ be a diffusion process driven by a two-dimension brownian motion $w_t$.

$$dx_t = \mu(t, x_t) dt + \sigma(x_t, t)dw_t$$

where, $\mu$ is 2*1 and $\sigma$ is 2 * 2.

The book I am reading, is saying that the generator of function f is the following manner...
$$
Lf(x) = \mu(t, x)Df(x) + \frac12 Tr \{\sigma(t, x) \sigma(t, x)^T D^2f(x)\}
$$

I can't wrap my mind around the last term with trace.

Let,
$$
\sigma = \left(\begin{array}{cc} \sigma_{1,1} & \sigma_{1,2}\\ \sigma_{2,1} & \sigma_{2,2} \end{array}\right)
$$

then I can't get the result consistent with the 1-dimentional setting by doing ...
$$tr
\left(\begin{array}{cc} \sigma_{1,1} & \sigma_{1,2}\\ \sigma_{2,1} & \sigma_{2,2} \end{array}\right) 
*
\left(\begin{array}{cc} \sigma_{1,1} & \sigma_{1,2}\\ \sigma_{2,1} & \sigma_{2,2} \end{array}\right)^T
*
\left(\begin{array}{cc} f_{x1,x1} & f_{x1,x2}\\ f_{x2,x1} & f_{x2,x2} \end{array}\right)
$$

Can anyone help me take a look at the previous formula, and give me an idea how it is reduced to the familiar formula without trace? (i.e.  ($\sigma_{11} f_{xx} + \sigma_{22} f_{yy} + \sigma_{12}f_{xy} + \sigma_{21}f_{yx}$))

Comment: Did you actually compute the trace? When you take the product of the 3 matrices you get some matrix. Then when you take the trace you take the sum of the diagonal entries, which should reduce to what you want.

Comment: I did compute the trace, but it doesn't match...

Comment: @TheManWhoNeverSleeps For example, the first element after multiplying the first two matrices is $\sigma_{1,1}^2 + \sigma_{1,2} * \sigma_{2,1}$. So this means the term $\sigma_{1,2} * \sigma_{2,1} * f_{x_1, x_1}$ will be in the final result, but it doesnt... unless I am making a mistake in the expected final result, the trace doesnt seem to be right.